# Removing span tags from soup BeautifulSoup/Python

Tags: python, html, dom, beautifulsoup

I have a soup in Python like this:

```
<p>
 <span style="text-decoration: underline; color: #3366ff;">
   Title:
 </span>
 Info
</p>
<p>
 <span style="color: #3366ff;">
  <span style="text-decoration: underline;">
   Title2:
  </span>
 </span>
 Info2
</p>
```

I'd like to get it to look like this:

```
<p>
   Title:
 Info
</p>
<p>
   Title2:
 Info2
</p>
```

Is there a way to do this with bs4?

Comment: Try this http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/

Comment: I don't think that's exactly what I want. Thanks though.

Comment: ok , please jsfiddle.net

Comment: Yes, but I'm trying to do this in Python because I'm web scraping.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You'll be wanting to use beautifulsoup's [unwrap()](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#unwrap) for this.

```
import bs4
soup1 = bs4.BeautifulSoup(htm1, 'html.parser')
for match in soup1.findAll('span'):
    match.unwrap()
print soup1
```

Answer (score 7):

You can also use `replace_with` to remove span tags:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
for span_tag in soup.findAll('span'):
    span_tag.replace_with('')
print(soup)
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this function if it can help :

```
def deleteBalise(string):
    for i in range(2):
        # identifying  <
        rankBegin = 0
        for carac in string:
            if carac == '<':
                break
            rankBegin += 1
        # identifying  >
        rankEnd = 0
        for carac in string:
            if carac == '>':
                break
            rankEnd += 1
        stringToReplace = string[rankBegin:rankEnd+1]
        string = string.replace(stringToReplace,'')
    return string
```

Comment: Bingo ! It helped me! tnx