# Replacing <p> and <br> tags in beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Hi I am currently looking for a way to replace tags in code with spaces.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup("<p>Something</p><p>Something</p>") 
print soup.get_text()

SomethingSomething

#When I do get_text now I would get SomethingSomething but I want Something Something
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22496822/removing-span-tags-from-soup-beautifulsoup-python

Comment: @Caramiriel Hi thanks for the response but I dont see how it helps, unwrap just removes the tag (I think)

Comment: Are you trying to just swap all <p> with <br>?

Comment: @Tygran: Well, implementing a visitor would be one way to do it, unpacking tags on the way. I see Rob has posted something more native to the library though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `get_text` function allows you to specify what separates the text of individual elements:

```
In [1]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [2]: soup = BeautifulSoup("<p>Something</p><p>Something</p>")

In [3]: print soup.get_text(separator=u' ')
Something Something
```

Refernce: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text