# how to remove span from the td in beautiful soup Python 3.5

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, yahoo-finance

I am scraping the Yahoo Finance website to get a companies stock data and i have used beautiful soup to extract td tag, however i want to remove the span tag and unable to do it. Below are few lines of my html code from which i need to extract the text.

```
[ < td class = "Py(10px) Ta(start)"
data - reactid = "53" > < span data - reactid = "54" > 31 - Jul - 2017 < /span></td > , < td class = "Py(10px)"
data - reactid = "55" > < span data - reactid = "56" > 991.90 < /span></td > , < td class = "Py(10px)"
data - reactid = "57" > < span data - reactid = "58" > 1, 021.70 < /span></td > , < td class = "Py(10px)"
data - reactid = "59" > < span data - reactid = "60" > 986.75 < /span></td > , < td class = "Py(10px)"
data - reactid = "61" > < span data - reactid = "62" > 1, 011.20 < /span></td >
```

]

My code below gives me the above content.

```
INFY = url.urlopen("https://in.finance.yahoo.com/quote/INFY.NS/history?p=INFY.NS")
INFYHis = INFY.read()
INFYSoup = soup(INFYHis,'html.parser')
INFYtd=INFYSoup.findAll("td",{"class":"Py(10px)"})
```

I am very new to python and not sure how to get remove or get text for my analysis.

Comment: So do you want to remove it or get text?

Comment: Yes, i need to get the text and have it in the form of dataframe so that i can use it as pandas datafrome

Answer (score 1):

You can use BeautifulSoup's [unwrap()](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#unwrap) method for this.

Just add these two extra two lines to filter the `<span>` tag content from the `INFYSoup` content before extracting the `Py(10px)` class:

```
INFYSoup = soup(INFYHis,'html.parser')

for match in INFYSoup.find_all('span'):  # add these two extra two lines 
    match.unwrap()                       # to filter the `<span>` tag content first

# then proceed as usual
INFYtd=INFYSoup.findAll("td",{"class":"Py(10px)"})

for child in INFYtd:
    print child
```

Demo:

```
<td class="Py(10px) Ta(start)" data-reactid="53">31-Jul-2017</td>
<td class="Py(10px)" data-reactid="55">991.90</td>
...
...
<td class="Py(10px)" data-reactid="1540">992.59</td>
<td class="Py(10px)" data-reactid="1542">30,89,588</td>
```

Implemented based on answer in duplicate linked in the comments ([Removing span tags from soup BeautifulSoup/Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22496822/1248974)).

Comment: Thank you i tried your code and removed <span>, however i got another code which i used to make it work.

Comment: @KeertheshKumar, great to hear you made it work! Good job! 